# Raven db: creating a new database

Tags: ravendb

I am new to raven db. I have read the API and try to create a database . It has something like EnsureDatabaseExists function which creates the database if it does not exist. It actually uses DocumentDatabase type to create that database. I use it and it creates the database but I want to use this object directly so that using this object I can directly work with documents. Am i doing right? Or can there be any better approach then this to work with documents.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing the database document and querying documents.

The database document is a document on the default database, which just represent a database in RavenDB which is not the default database. It stores some data like the database name and location. You, as a consumer of ravendb as nothing to do with this document. And this has nothing to do with querying any other documents.

Look [here](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/basic-operations) in order to learn how to query ravendb for documents. In order to query a specific database, if you work just with that database than you better just specify the database name in the [connection string](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/connecting-to-a-ravendb-datastore). If you work against multiy databases at once, you can specify the database name that you want when you open a session, `store.OpenSession("database-name")`.

Answer (score 0):

Three methods are available on `store.DatabaseCommands.GlobalAdmin`.

- `GetDatabaseNames`: lists database names
- `EnsureDatabaseExists`: creates database if it does not exists
- `CreateDatabase`: creates database

Note that `DocumentStore.Initialize()` already ensures that the database is created. You can pass a boolean false to avoid this behavior.

```cs
// init store object, you pass the service URL + the database name
var store = new DocumentStore("http://localhost:8001/databases/MyNewDataBase");
store.Initialize(false);

// most simple thing is:
var dbName = store.DefaultDatabase;
store.DatabaseCommands.GlobalAdmin.EnsureDatabaseExists(dbName);
```

If you want to check without creating:

```
// there is a method to list the database names
bool exists = false;
for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
{
    var names = store.DatabaseCommands.GlobalAdmin.GetDatabaseNames(100, i * 100);    
    if (names.Contains(dbName))
    {
        exists = true;
        break;
    }

    if (names.Length < 100)
    {
        // no more databases
        break;
    }
}

if (exists)
{
    // database exists, do something
}
```

Reference: https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/Csharp/client-api/commands/how-to/create-delete-database